# Copy properties in javascript?? the definitive Guide 6th?

Tags: javascript, properties, copy

```
function extend(o, p) {
    for(prop in p) {                        
        o[prop] = p[prop];                  
    }
    return o;
}
function o() {};
function p(){};
p.name='caicai';
p.show=function(){ alert(this.name);};
p.show(); // output p
extend(o, p);
o.show(); // output o
```

why the "output" in here? why not to output 'caicai'.

```
function extend(o, p) {
    for(prop in p) {                        
        o[prop] = p[prop];                  
    }
    return o;
}
function o() {};
function p(){};
p.poo='caicai';
p.show=function(){ alert(this.poo);};
p.show(); // output 'caicai'
extend(o, p);
o.show(); // output 'caicai'
```

BUT  in here ?
why the "output" in here? why not to output 'caicai'.

Comment: Repeating sentences does not make your question more interesting.

Comment: Please use proper English when you ask your questions. Thanks.

Comment: English is obviously not his first language, but I think that's far from the biggest problem with this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: This is not related to the `extend` function.

`o` and `p` are functions. [`Function.name` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Name) is a non-standard property and cannot be overridden.

Example:

```
> function foo() {}
  undefined
> foo.name
  "foo"
> foo.name = 'bar';  // assigning a new value
  "bar"
> foo.name           // does not work
  "foo"
```

If you'd declare `o` and `p` as objects, then it would work:

```
> var foo = {};
  undefined
> foo.name
  undefined
> foo.name = 'bar';
  "bar"
> foo.name
  "bar"
```

Comment: Yup, and I don't think it's available in all browsers anyway. Probably best not to use the reserved keyword and pick some other attr name instead.

Comment: all the browser should be?? or only firefox?

Comment: @caizZZz: If you follow the link in my answer, you will find this sentence: *"Functions created with the syntax `new Function(...)` or just `Function(...)` have their name property set to "anonymous" on Firefox and Safari, or to an empty string on Chrome and Opera. This property is not supported on Internet Explorer."*. Which means that this property exists in Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Opera, but not in IE. Whether or not it is readonly in all the browsers, I don't know, but the fact that it is in Chrome already suggests not to use it.